# I am trying to solve Min Cost problem in AMPL, but my objective function is 0

Tags: optimization, ampl, minimum-cut

I am new to AMPL and doing MC problem. I have included my code. I asked earlier to help with other errors, at this moment program is working, but optimal solution is 0 and giving a strange error. What can be a problem? Maybe my constraints are wrong?

Error:

> Error executing "solve" command:
> error processing constraint c2[1,1]:
> invalid subscript flow[1,4,1]

Code:

```
set NODES;  #define set of nodes
set ARCS within {NODES, NODES};
set COMMODITIES;
param demand {COMMODITIES};
param origin {COMMODITIES};
param dest {COMMODITIES};
param cap{ARCS} >= 0;
param cost{ARCS} >= 0;


# Decision Variables
var flow{(u,v,k) in ARCS cross COMMODITIES};   #flow assos with commodity k
var x{(u,v,k) in ARCS cross COMMODITIES} binary;  #fraction of flow assos with commodity k

# Objective Function
minimize Total_Cost:
   sum {(u,v) in ARCS, k in COMMODITIES}
      cost [u,v] *(flow[u,v,k]*x[u,v,k]);
      
# Capacity constraints
subject to c1 {(u,v) in ARCS}:
    sum{(u,v,k) in ARCS cross COMMODITIES} 
    (flow[u,v,k]*x[u,v,k]) <= cap[u,v];
 
    
#Flow conservation constraints
subject to c2 {k in COMMODITIES, u in NODES diff {origin[k], dest[k]}}:
    sum{(v,u) in ARCS} (flow[u,v,k]*x[v,u,k]) - sum{(u,v) in ARCS} (flow[u,v,k]*x[u,v,k]) = 0;
    
     
# Source and sink constraints
subject to c3{k in COMMODITIES, u in NODES diff {origin[k],dest[k]}}:
    sum{(u,v) in ARCS} flow[u,v,k] - sum{(v,u) in ARCS} flow[v,u,k] =
        if u = origin[k] then demand[k] else if u = dest[k] then -demand[k] else 0;
            
 
# Commodity flow constraints
subject to c4 {(u,v,k) in ARCS cross COMMODITIES}:
    flow[u,v,k] <= x[u,v,k] * cap[u,v]; 
        
# Non-negativity constraints
subject to c5 {(u,v,k) in ARCS cross COMMODITIES}:
    x[u,v,k] >= 0;
 
      
data;

set NODES := 1 2 3 4 5 6;

param: ARCS:   cost  cap  :=
       1,2     3      15
       2,3     6      1
       4,1     8      6
       2,5     4      10
       2,4     4      10
       3,4     3      6
       3,6     8      7
       5,3     12     4
       4,6     10     8 ;
  
param: COMMODITIES: origin dest    demand :=
           1           3    5      6
           2           1    6      4;
```

Program doesn't have an errors, but optimal solution is 0. I don't understand where is the problem, which constrains are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In constraint `c2` you have the following:

```
sum{(v,u) in ARCS} (flow[u,v,k]*x[v,u,k])
```

However, `flow` is indexed over ARCS. If there is an arc `(v,u)` in ARCS, there is not guarantee of that there is also an arc `(u,v)` (opposite direction) and in that case `flow[u,v,k]` will be an invalid subscript.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer! I understand that my constraints doesn't apply a mutual direction. Maybe you have a tip how better to write this constrain? Because when add another one (constrain) with opposite direction it's wouldn't work.

Comment: You can filter for ARCS for which there is a reverse arc: `sum{(v,u) in ARCS: (u,v) in ARCS} (flow[u,v,k]*x[v,u,k])`